# Switching from Wordpress to Drupal Search Engine Problems

Tags: wordpress, drupal

I have been running a WP site for a little over 6 months now and I'm beginning to run into WP limitations on post styles (yes, I know about WP3's post types).

I would like to completely change the site over to Drupal, but I'm worried about the Search Engine effects.

For instance: We have finally just put on many pages images on Google Images - we will lose all those? Will it cause the site to get blacklisted due to the change? Or will Google recognize the site's change and just reindex the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you have referenced images in the content hosted on Google Images, or you uploaded images to Google for use in the content?

Either way, you shouldn't have any short or long term affects with SEO, as long as you institute the same SEO in your site when converting. For example, meta tags, meta keywords, description, site name etc.

Check out these modules:

- http://drupal.org/project/nodewords
- http://drupal.org/project/seo_checklist
- http://drupal.org/project/page_title
- http://drupal.org/project/wordpress_import
- http://drupal.org/project/contentoptimizer
- http://drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap

Answer (score 0):

Also, `Nodewords 1.13` and newer can let you add the OpenGraph meta tags, which are used with Facebook to provide the customized summary blocks when you bookmark a page.

Comment: You shouldn't sign every answer you post. Update your bio on your profile instead.